# Editing Wordpress Permissions in LAMP - Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: permissions, linux

I'm hosting a local version of my wordpress theme on Ubuntu 11.10.  However, LAMP is installed in a directory that requires sudo privileges.  When I try to add images or any outside content to my theme, it fails because it cannot create a folder/write to a folder.

How do I edit the permissions to allow Wordpress the access it needs?

Comment: This should be asked in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Can you login to terminal? This should be over in serverfault. Navigate to /var/www/ and do ls -l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that setting all to 777 is not the most secure option.

Basically, my favourite is to change the wordpress to the webserver's owner. Being:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

So that the webserver is responsible for handling changes.

Also, you can change the rights to 755 for the whole /var/www branch

```
sudo chmod -R -c 755 /var/www/
```

Finally, allow your wp-content/ folder in 775 ( so that you can edit files from the WordPress backend without having to upload files via FTP. ( Not necessarily a best practice but useful from time to time ) via

```
sudo chmod -R -c 775 /var/www/WORDPRESS/wp-contents/
```

And you will have a reasonable setup with uploads, editing from backend and a minimum level of security.

Comment: Sorry I never accepted your answer.  I just happened to stumble across it.  It helped me at the time and its continued to help me to this day!

Comment: Should the first one be `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www` or the way you suggest it? DigitalOcean recommends this way. What is the difference?

Comment: Ok, `www-data:www-data` worked, but I thought I read that this lowers security. I read another solution that said to add `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to `wp-config.php` [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/wordpress-on-localhost-lamp-doesnt-let-me-install-plugins/19702#19702)