# FTP credentials on localhost

Tags: ftp, local-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wordpress on localhost lamp doesn't let me install plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/wordpress-on-localhost-lamp-doesnt-let-me-install-plugins)

I just started working locally with Wordpress. Trying to update theme/plugins I get asked for my FTP credentials and I get really confused...what the heck is my FTP credentials when working locally?

Comment: This is a permissions issue. You gotta change the owner/group settings of `wp-content/uploads` folder, maybe of all `wp-content`. Downvoted and flagged as Possible Duplicate: [wordpress on localhost lamp doesn't let me install plugins](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19649/12615)

Comment: The below answer helped me fix it. I had to set owner and group to _www in the Mamp Pro permission settings.

Comment: Ok, but please search before posting :)

Comment: I did search but I didn't find that post for any reason, maybe I didn't look hard enough. Will try to do better next time :)

Comment: Just add `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to `wp-config.php` and it will work on localhost. Just make sure you don't add it to production version. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: define('FS_METHOD','direct'); - helped me. Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: define('FS_METHOD','direct'); worked for me aswell.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Set file permissions**

On Mac OS X (Leopard), the Apache HTTP Server runs under the user account, _www which belongs to the group _www. To allow WordPress to configure wp-config.php during installation, update files during upgrades, and update the .htaccess file for pretty permalinks, give the server write permission on the files.

One way to do this is to change the owner of the wordpress directory and its contents to _www. Keep the group as staff, a group to which your user account belongs and give write permissions to the group.

```
$ cd /<wherever>/Sites/<thesite>
$ sudo chown -R _www wordpress
$ sudo chmod -R g+w wordpress
```

This way, the WordPress directories have a permission level of 775 and files have a permission level of 664. No file nor directory is world-writeable.

You can read more about it on mamp forum: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15917

Comment: Thank you. I use Mamp Pro and in the permissions box I set the Owner and Group to _www - Your answer led me to it.

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time with plugins and setting up wordpress. Thank you! If you could point me to a good tutorial about chown and chmod, and file privileges you would help even more (the current link is not working).

Comment: Glad it helped you. look at this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19898/whats-the-simplest-way-to-edit-and-add-files-to-var-www

Comment: That worked brilliantly!

Comment: 2015 and this still fixes it!

Comment: To make it work with XAMPP on mac change sudo chown -R _www wordpress to sudo chown -R daemon wordpress

Comment: 12-2016 and this still fixes it! @Rvervuurt

Comment: 10/2018 and this fixes it :D - thanks so much!

Comment: This worked for me, lots of thanks and an upvote

Comment: 01/2020 This works great