# to perform the requested action wordpress needs to access your web server. please enter your ftp

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, permissions

I'm following [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress), yet when I'm try to update and/or install `plugin` and/or `theme` through `wp-admin`, I'm getting following:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web
>   server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
>   remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

from file system level:

```
# ls -ld wp-content/ wp-content/plugins/ wp-content/themes/
drwxrwxr-x.  6 root apache 4096 Jun  2 12:01 wp-content/
drwxrwxr-x. 28 root apache 4096 Jun  2 00:00 wp-content/plugins/
drwxrwxr-x. 11 root apache 4096 May 11 16:34 wp-content/themes/
#
```

`httpd` runs as `apache`:

```
$ ps auxw | grep httpd
root     20158  0.0  0.1 533080 26192 ?        Ss   15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20233  0.0  0.2 612608 34908 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20234  0.0  0.2 538772 46904 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20235  0.0  0.1 536832 24268 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20236  0.0  0.2 626272 35640 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20237  0.0  0.0 535296  9592 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20322  0.0  0.1 537088 26620 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20380  0.0  0.2 626060 33816 ?        S    15:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20429  0.0  0.1 538216 29184 ?        S    15:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20447  0.0  0.2 629380 43180 ?        S    15:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   20448  0.0  0.2 626172 35224 ?        S    15:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
alexus   24073  0.0  0.0 112652   972 pts/9    R+   15:13   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
$
```

I'd like to be able to perform requested action (`install` and/or `update`) through `/wp-admin` *without* FTP credentials.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this a localhost installation? If so, see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/wordpress-on-localhost-lamp-doesnt-let-me-install-plugins

Comment: @GregMcMullen no, this is *NOT* localhost installation &  "accepted" answer from link that you comment is to recursively change ownership of a wordpress directory to `nobody` - this won't work for me due to `httpd` runs as `apache`.

Comment: @alexus It looks like your files are owned by root.apache at the moment. Did you try apache.apache instead of nobody?

Comment: @TimMalone setting files/directory as `apache.apache` or `root.apache` wouldn't make any difference, as long as `httpd` runs as `apache`, and `apache`'s `uid` is part of `apache` `gid`'s group, it's all the same, because my permissions set to `g+w`.

Comment: @alexus Ok, something else to try - set FS_METHOD to 'direct' in wp-config.php (https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants)

Comment: @TimMalone per https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants - `Note that your selection here has serious security implications.`

Comment: @alexus See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189554/what-security-concerns-should-i-have-when-setting-fs-method-to-direct-in-wp-co

Answer (score 178):

Add the following to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189554/what-security-concerns-should-i-have-when-setting-fs-method-to-direct-in-wp-co

Comment: worked for me unless you have bad permissions in the file system. Btw I added it at the very top of the wp-config.php

Comment: Make sure to read the post Alexus linked to before using this method.  This method definitely works (it solved the problem for me), but you should definitely not use this method in a shared hosting environment or any at-risk environment where you could compromise security by doing this.

Comment: after adding this I have getting this error:

`Update Failed: The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.`

Comment: This is potentially dangerous for users who migrate their entire sites from localhost to a live server. I'd prefer you use @Syamraj K's method of modifying file permissions, or take this out of your `wp-config.php` before migrating online

Comment: dude!! you are my hero. thanks for saving hours of my time for this

Comment: If you like using WP CLI, you can run this command instead: `wp config set FS_METHOD direct` . This will modify `wp-config.php`

Comment: Please explain what this does before having so many blindly insert this into their config file.

Answer (score 32):

This means that WordPress is having limited permission for making changes in the folder that it was installed.

In-order to fix this, all that you need to do is provide necessary permissions for the same.

Run the following Command in your Terminal / Putty / Commandline Prompt after connecting to your Server via SSH:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Comment: permissions are fine, re-read my question)

Comment: chown: invalid user: ‘apache:apache’

Comment: Remember, Apache can be different users in different flavors of Linux.  So you can try groups <username> and see if it errors out or not, since the user and group for Apache is usually the same.  Then use the correct user.  The most common in Ubuntu is  "www-data:www-data" or "www:www" for chown-ing Apache files.

Comment: After I could find the right user name this worked just great (see also [command to list all users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users/410274#410274))

Comment: In case you want to use it on OSX, use _www:_www (Mojave, don't know what it wolud be in other versions)

Comment: This is a better answer. The more upvoted answer is dangerous for many ignorant users who migrate entire website directories from localhost to a live server, even when using WordPress plugins

Comment: Worked Like Charm :) avoid using define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );

Answer (score 10):

Even though it is totally correct to have the ownership as `root:apache` with permissions 775, and httpd to run as `apache`, Wordpress does not like this. It wants the owner to be `apache`, as per `wp-admin/includes/file.php`:

```
    // Attempt to determine the file owner of the WordPress files, and that of newly created files
   $wp_file_owner = $temp_file_owner = false;
   if ( function_exists('fileowner') ) {
      $wp_file_owner = @fileowner( __FILE__ );
      $temp_file_owner = @fileowner( $temp_file_name );
  }
```

Yours would be:
wp_file_owner = root
temp_file_owner = apache

```
if ( $wp_file_owner !== false && $wp_file_owner === $temp_file_owner ) {
    // WordPress is creating files as the same owner as the WordPress files,
    // this means it's safe to modify & create new files via PHP.
    $method = 'direct';
    $GLOBALS['_wp_filesystem_direct_method'] = 'file_owner';
} elseif ( $allow_relaxed_file_ownership ) {
    // The $context directory is writable, and $allow_relaxed_file_ownership is set, this means we can modify files
    // safely in this directory. This mode doesn't create new files, only alter existing ones.
    $method = 'direct';
    $GLOBALS['_wp_filesystem_direct_method'] = 'relaxed_ownership';
}
```

If $wp_file_owner is same as $temp_file_owner then proceed. Yours would be caught in the elseif, which according to the comment does not allow delete/create, but only updates (I verified this by updating the code of a plugin from within Wordpress, and it worked).

Note I did not extensively look through the code, this is just my quick interpretation. I had the same problem and once I switched user:group so that the httpd user is also the file owner, it did not prompt for FTP credentials anymore.

Comment: Yup, changing the owner to `www-data` worked for me. Funny WordPress!

Comment: interesting find, i will look into that... thank you +1 from me)

Comment: Just in case anyone's having this problem - this only worked if I changed the owner of ALL the WordPress files/directories to my webserver user. Just changing the wp-content directory and all its children did not solve the problem. I had to recursively change the wordpress root directory and all children for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but probably has to be said - this is one problem you should avoid solving unless you are talking about a local development in which case you can just set permissions to 777.

The reason is that if the webserver can overwrite your code, then any malicious code running on it will be able to do that as well. The risk is just so much bigger than the convenience of saving few seconds by not having to type the ftp credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is not that new anymore I want to add my two cents on this issue also.

A lot of ppl have Centos(7) on their VPS server and following code lines could solve their problem.

Imho has all to do with SELinux which withholds WordPress from doing it's job as wished. It goes to far to explain what [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) is and what it does. FYI the introduction starts with:

> Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) is a mandatory access control (MAC) security mechanism implemented in the kernel.

*Only 3 steps to folow:*

- 1 Open a terminal (or access the server through SSH)
- 2 Add following code line
  `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/wordpress`
- 3 Add second code line
  `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/wordpress`

> No reboot from the server or restart from any daemon needed.

I won't say it helps everybody but for those who didn't disable SELinux it should be a relieve.

Cheers

**Note: Please adjust to your own needs (meaning path to WordPress)**

*edit: be sure to remove the line `define("FS_METHOD", "direct");` when it is/was used in `wp-config.php` because that's absolutely a no go when above code lines do as wanted.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this by switching from GIT back to FTP mode.

No more warning.

Perhaps that'll help somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your wp-config.php file in between the 2 comments

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Comment: That's the same as the existing top voted answer except for the comments. Does that really matter?

Comment: I added the answer because, knowing where to add the code would really help another beginner like me :)