# Install (enable) plugins on multisite, on localhost

Tags: plugins, multisite, ftp

From the North!

I have WP 5.2.3 running, as Multisite, on localhost.

I would like to install plugins at the Network level, so that I can enable them on individual sites.

I go to My Sites > Network Admin > Plugins

I click Add New

I search for Simply Static, and find it.

I click on Install Now, then get a dialog asking for FTP credentials.

I have installed plugins on localhost (single site) before, without getting a request for FTP credentials.

Is a way besides FTP to install plugins on multisite?

If so, how should I proceed?

Can wordpress.org possibly access my localhost via FTP?

If so, I am unsure what credentials to give. Do I need to create a new set of credentials?

If so, how do I proceed?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.

I found an answer that works.

add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to wp-config.php

found at [wordpress on localhost lamp doesn't let me install plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/wordpress-on-localhost-lamp-doesnt-let-me-install-plugins/202731#202731)